# WCF client Configure method not automatically being called

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, webservice-client

I am configuring a WCF client service programmatically, this is because we are executing libraries in a third-party sandbox where we have no control of the AppDomains configuration file.

The problem is that the standard 'public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)' isn't being called automatically, this results in the client not being configured.

Here's the client with the static Configure method:

```
namespace OpenIt.service
{
    public class CustomerClient : ClientBase<ICustomerClient>, ICustomerClient
    {
        public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding
            {
                TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed
            };

            var serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ICustomerClient)), binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:3245")));

            serviceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior
            {
                DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json
            });

            config.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceEndpoint);

            config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });
        }

        public GetCustomerResponse GetCustomer(GetCustomerRequest request)
        {
            using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)Channel))
            {
                GetCustomerResponse response = Channel.GetCustomer(request);

                return response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the interface:

```
namespace OpenI
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICustomerClient
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "rest/v6/customerMan/customer/GetCustomer")]
        GetCustomerResponse GetCustomer(GetCustomerRequest request);
    }
}
```

Here's the initialization and call:

```
private bool Testit()
{
    //Here it fails due to no config
    var client = new CustomerClient();

    GetCustomerResponse response = client.GetCustomer(new GetCustomerRequest { CustomerNumber = "001" });
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the 'public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)' method isn't automatically being called? Am I missing something where 'CustomerClient()' is initialized under 'Testit()'.

The webservice is fine, tested with postman.

Answer (score 0):

This method is used to configure WCF services, not clients.

Strong hint is that the parameter is of type `ServiceConfiguration`.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/configuring-wcf-services-in-code) for details.

To configure a client, you can use the methods (and constructors) on `ClientBase` and/or `app.config` settings ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-client-overview#obtain-the-service-contract-bindings-and-addresses)).